# Why no authorization prompt in potloc?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

I'm using [potloc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/PotLoc/Introduction/Intro.html) as a tutorial, but it won't start receiving locations.
I think I have narrowed it down to the fact that `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()`
is being called, but no prompt is appearing on the watch sim.

I have added the missing `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` to the WatchKit Extension's Info.plist.

When I run through the debugger, it gets to

```
case .notDetermined:
            isRequestingLocation = true
            requestLocationButton.setTitle(cancelTitle)
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

But no prompt is raised on the watch.

Running xCode 9.1 on Mac OS 10.13.1

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky, you may need to fill: Display name, bundle identifier, capabilites (all of it), add the Core Location framework (re-add it)

Comment: Tricky????
As I said, I'm using it as a tutorial, and this is definitely not  Swift 101.
Please, can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Thanks, for that.
Many of the fields were populated, but greyed-out. I completed them with the greyed-out values and now it's all working.
The why's and wherefore's are entirely obscure to me, but may become clearer as I progress.

Comment: @StarTraX, T can not be more specific... because there is no documentation about it, even with WWDC videos says that it should be automatic and it is not for WatchOS target. After hours of try/redo I found that this was the issue, fill all the need plist/target fields. This is not the case of iOS